# Forming tree structure in lwc component with single custom object

Tags: apex, lightningtreegrid, tree-component

I have a scenario to build tree structure for an custom object which has its two own lookups(Parent and Alternate Parent).
I need to form a tree like
[image: Parent Child1 child a abc 1 (For abc1, Child1 is Parent and child a is Alt Parent) abc2 (for abc2, Child 1 is parent and no alternate parent).]

All there record has comes under same record of Custom obj 2.
My scenario is,
For Custom obj2 named Plant1, then I have query all the records of Custom obj1 (Sites) and to display then as tree in lwc component.

Please suggest me ideas and share some code samples.

Comment: What you have tried so far? where you are stuck?

Comment: @rahulgawale I am stuck in Parent & Alternate parent mapping. Don't know how to map child with corresponding parent. If it has alt parent then I need to map with that. In my case, record cannot have direct relationship with parent. In the above picture, child of `child -a of child1` have the direct relationship with child 1 but it has alternate parent - child a. I don't know how to make like this.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to build complete hierarchy in one go. It would make sense to break this in smaller pieces if the idea is to display.

Assuming that when the tree grid loads you only query the top level data i.e. parent records. The tree grid has a feature of asynchronous expanding of rows which can be utilized  to load all first level children of Parent record when you expand parent record.

The same logic is applied when first level child child is expanded. In that case you query the second level children.

Let me know if I have misunderstood this.